# How to upload a file remotely to a MySQL database with jdbc, servlets and html

Tags: html, mysql, tomcat, servlets, jdbc

I´ve been trying to upload a file remotely from an html page to a servlet and then saving it in a database, so far I have managed to do it locally, but when using another computer in the same network, I get and error explaining that the system could not find the specified file.
I am using the following form to take in the files:

```
       <form method="post" action="UploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">                    
       <tr>
          <td><Input name="name" type="text"></td>
          <td><Input name="client_ID" type="text" required></td>
          <td><input name="date" type="date"></td>
          <td><input name="pdf" type="file"></td>
          <td><input name="xml" type="file"></td>
      </tr>
      </form>
```

Which links to the following action in the servlet:

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/database";
    Connection con;
    String path1=request.getParameter("pdf");
    String path2=request.getParameter("xml");
    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    String date=request.getParameter("date");
    String client=request.getParameter("client_ID");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user", "password");
    PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement("insert into table(pdf, xml, date, client, employee_ID, client_ID) values(?,?,?,?,1,?)");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(path1));
    stat.setBlob(1,is);
    InputStream is2 = new FileInputStream(new File(path2));
    stat.setBlob(2,is2);
    stat.setString(3,date);
    stat.setString(4,name);
    stat.setString(5,client);
```

And throws the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.pdf (The system could not find the specified file)
```

I understand that the problem comes from the servlet trying to upload the file from the host machine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it's a bad practice to store file in database directly,you should store file in   your server disk and only store the path of the file

Comment: Sorry, I am new to databases but is there a way to do it with this Blob method I am using?

Answer (score 0):

This questions is duplicate of this.
[read the contents of a file upload in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099956/read-the-contents-of-a-file-upload-in-java)

1. You have to first save the file to local hardisk.
2. Send the local hardisk file to MySql database.

Reading the streams and saving it local hardisk.

```
     String path1=request.getParameter("pdf");
     //read this and save the content to local harddisk, location e.g. C:\\temp\\A.pdf
     String path2=request.getParameter("xml");
     //read this and save the content to local harddisk, location e.g. C:\\temp\\B.xml
```

Now, pass the local path to MySql Query.

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\tmp\A.pdf"));
stat.setBlob(1,is);
InputStream is2 = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\tmp\B.xml"));
stat.setBlob(2,is2);
```

Comment: It is not necessary to save the file to the disk, first. There are many reasons one may want to avoid a disk-based file: performance, security, or deployment details (e.g. read-only disk on app server).

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the filename from the request, but then you are attempting to read the file contents from the disk when the file contents are in fact *in the request*.

Try this to get yourself started:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/database";
Connection con;
String name=request.getParameter("name");
String date=request.getParameter("date");
String client=request.getParameter("client_ID");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user", "password");
PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement("insert into table(pdf, xml, date, client, employee_ID, client_ID) values(?,?,?,?,1,?)");

javax.servlet.http.Part pdf = request.getPart("pdf"); // <-- get multipart part from request
InputStream is = pdf.getInputStream();                // <-- get input stream from multipart part
javax.servlet.http.Part xml = request.getPart("xml"); // <-- get multipart part from request
InputStream is2 = xml.getInputStream();                // <-- get input stream from multipart part

stat.setBlob(1,is);
stat.setBlob(2,is2);
stat.setString(3,date);
stat.setString(4,name);
stat.setString(5,client);
```

Now... there are a bunch of other issues with your code that should be addressed later when you've got this working. In no particular order, they are:

1. Validate all the inputs you get to make sure they are sane. Is it okay for me to upload a 2GiB document into your database? What about a file with a PDF extension which is actually an XML file? What about the reverse? IF you expect the PDF file to be a PDF and the XML file to be XML, you'd better check to make sure that's what the client is sending. Don't insert anything into your database that you haven't inspected to make sure it's legitimate and appropriate.
2. Use a JDBC connection pool. Stop calling `Class.forName()` and `DriverManager.getConnection()` on every request.
3. Re-factor your code into separate pieces: one for obtaining the data from the request and one for writing it to the database. There is no good reason to perform both HTTP and JDBC activities from the same piece of code. What is this, PHP?
4. Resource management: make sure all of your closable resources are properly-managed using `try/catch/finally` blocks to clean everything up. This includes `Part` items, which should have their `delete()` method called when you are finished with them.